# Can't add printer on Windows XP

Tags: printing

I've added a HP 4250 printer to about half a dozen Windows XP PCs in our office without any problems whatsoever, but for some reason I haven't been able to add it to one particular PC today.

I go through the Add Printer wizard to add a local printer attached to the PC, enter the new port number as a Standard TCP/IP Port, install the driver. At the end of the wizard I get the following error message:

*Full error message: "windows cannot connect to the printer. either the printer name was typed incorrectly, or the specified printer has lost its connection to the server."*

This doesn't make any sense as I am able to ping the printer from the PC. The print spooler is running, and any firewall software on the local PC is switched off.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and came to the conclusion the problem was with the printer driver.  I was using the HP Universal print driver, and I think it did not install properly or was corrupted in some way. You might find that switching to a more "generic" PCL 5 driver, say perhaps the HP 5N PCL5 printer driver, might work better...

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to fix the problem. So I mapped the the user to another printer as a workaround

Comment: Glad you resolved [or created a work around for] this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.